# vscode verbose mode - show all commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

Setting up VSCode and learning that keyboard bindings issues relate to precedent and when context.

Is it possible to get the value of a setting (like a toggle, or a current context like
**editorLangId** or **notebookType**), or even ALL values (perhaps filterable)? Either writing to file, or terminal, or status bar / custom debug panel...

Tried using inspect context keys and dev tools, now looking at extensions to understand the active and inactive and available contexts (and related info) for **when** config, to hopefully start making some keyboard shortcuts work.

Spoilt for choice on the marketplace! This looks good
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IPcorp.vsccontextscript

Comment: do a command search for `dev`, and use the command that dumps the context keys to the Dev console

Comment: I don't understand. you said you used insepct context keys and the dev tools. that's exactly what I'd suggest to do for your question. why isn't that satisfactory for you? what is it missing that you want?